# Hibernate configuration for oracle issue :ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I set the connection pool, changed the job processes for oracle. But still getting this error :
ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack
The Connection descriptor used by the client was

Is there any specific configuration other than connection pool or oracle job process setting that needs to be done for resolving this error

Answer (score 2):

The above solution only masks the problem. After almost die, I found a solution that really works. For some reason, Oracle driver running with hibernate OracleDialect (or Oracle10gDialect) needs extra parameters.

I was mapping my jdbc connection through Spring using

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mydb" />
    <property name="username" value="mydbuser" />
    <property name="password" value="12345" />
   </bean>
```

Then, I changed it to use JNDI:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb" />
</bean>
```

With this information in my context.xml (Tomcat):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        auth="Container"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mydb"
        username="mydbuser"
        password="12345"
        maxActive="20"
        maxIdle="10"
        maxWait="-1"
        validationQuery="select 1 from dual" />
```

This solves my problem. Probably one of the following configurations **maxActive**, **maxIdle** or **maxWait** provides to Oracle a needed value to close the session and return it to the pool. I keep this way in my system, as I had a pending task to migrate to JNDI, however, if you do not want to use JNDI, try to search similar values in **hibernateProperties** that might work.

Obs.: JNDI can be used in Jetty adding  tag of class *org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource* to *jetty.xml*.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This solved my problem, run this query with DBA:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET PROCESSES=150 SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and also were used the DriverManagerDataSource of Spring as the mchamati. However, I was not using tomcat or other middle application server to use JNDI solution proposed by him. I resolved replacing DriverManagerDataSource for a specific extension for Oracle that is part of the "Spring Data Project" (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc-ext/) and now works.

I resolved as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:orcl="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl/spring-data-orcl-1.0.xsd">

    <orcl:pooling-datasource id="datasource"
                             url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"
                             username="myusername"
                             password="mysupersecretpassword"
            connection-caching-enabled="true">
        <orcl:connection-properties>
            v$session.program=MyApplicationName
        </orcl:connection-properties>
    </orcl:pooling-datasource>

</beans>
```

There were conflicts because of different versions of the Spring Framework in pom.xml dependencies. So, I had to decalre the dependency in may pom.xml as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Link for complete instructions: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datasource.html